# Why YouCompleteMe vim plugin showed function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>114_SetUpPython error when start vim?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, plugins, vundle

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I followed this guide to install YouCompleteMe vim plugin:

> http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#ubuntu-linux-x64-super-quick-installation

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And add this to my ~/.vimrc file to run vundle install:

```
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

Then run it:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

But when I start a vim window, it showed me:

```
function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>114_SetUpPython has error:
line: 26:
```

My python version is:

```
python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

---

## Edit

Add error messages picture:

[image]

Comment: Is vim installed with python? Also that error message seems truncated. Is there more in `:messages`

Comment: Isn't it better for Ask Ubuntu? Not much to do with coding.

Comment: @FDinoff Just thought there are people better suited for this there. The answer might be better and quicker.

Comment: @FDinoff No, I installed vim by `sudo apt-get install vim`. I don't know how to see more error messages. If I type any key, it will open the vim editor.

Comment: @j-zhang Do `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`, you need to install a package that supports python.

Comment: @FDinoff Thank you. I have run `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`, but it seems the same result. The only difference is the code from 114 to 109 this time.

Comment: @j-zhang there has to be more to that error message.

Comment: @FDinoff I have added a error messages picture.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.